# Cannot edit list view columns in SPD 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, list-view

I am having an odd problem in SPD 2013. I need to be able to adjust the column width of my list columns, to make the layout more functional to the end user. I have previously achieved this by using the answer to this question on MSDN:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/07512437-fecf-4257-bcc8-ba3c8e467554/how-to-increase-width-of-a-list-in-sharepoint-designer-2013

I am not trying to duplicate the process, but when I go to enable the XML editing, it doesn't give me the choice to go in to the List View Tools, shown in the screenshot at the bottom of this post. This is trying to edit the default "AllItems" view. Any ideas on how to either enable the list view tools, or another way to widen my columns? And yes, I've moved my cursor around. That isn't the issue.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, figured it out thanks to this post that I had to do a lot of digging for. If you need this enabled, go to:

Web Part Tools > Properties (Under the Web Part group) > Miscellaneous, and check the Server Render box.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995791/list-view-tools-tab-missing-in-sharepoint-designer-2013